# How to properly extend the TPR Pipe on a water heater

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

Home inspection revealed that our TPR Pipe on the hot water heater was too short as it stops 18 inches above the floor. We need to fix it so that it is within 6 inches of the floor. I am hoping I can fix it by adding more copper pipe cut to length attached with shark bite push to connect fitting. Is that an acceptable fix? We are trying to avoid cost of hiring a plumber if possible.

Please note, the pipe originally comes out of the top of the water heater, so a straight tube replacement will not work unfortunately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy a replacement TPR drain tube for about $5 at any home improvement store.  Simply unscrew the old drain line, measure and cut the new line, then screw the new line in place.  You'll need two wrenches, and some PTFE tape (or whatever your preferred pipe dope is).

1. Place one wrench on the TPR valve, to prevent the valve from moving (a pipe wrench works well).
2. Place the other wrench on the drain tube.
3. Use the first wrench to hold the TPR in place, when you use the other to unscrew the drain pipe.
4. Cut the new pipe to length.
5. Apply PTFE tape (or your preferred pipe dope) to the threads of the pipe.
6. Use the two wrenches to install the new pipe.

***NOTE:*** This answer assumes a side discharge, threaded TPR valve.

---

Technically, you cannot use SharkBite® connectors on the temperature relief valve drain. Temperature relief valves can be set as high as 210°F, while SharkBite® connectors are only certified to 200°F. However, your local building department may allow it, so check with them to see if it's acceptable.

Comment: Thank you, however the pipe comes out of the top of the water heater then over and down the side, so a straight tube replacement would not work in this case. That is why I was looking for an easy fix to extend the pipe the extra 12 inches.

Comment: @JEH How are you at soldering?

Comment: I have never done it, so I was hoping a compression fitting would work.

Comment: @JEH See my update, you might have to try your hand at soldering.  Good news for you... The inspector will not check to make sure it doesn't leak, so no worries if it's not perfectly watertight.

Comment: If temp is the issue with using shark bite, I found a compression fitting at home depot that is rated up to 250 degrees. Do you think it would be found acceptable either way? 3/4 in. Copper Press x Press Pressure Repair Coupling with No Stop

Comment: @JEH Press fittings require a special tool to crimp the fitting.  They're not like the SharkBite push-fit fittings.  If you don't have the tool, or can't borrow it, it's much cheaper to buy a propane torch, some flux and solder (you can probably get a kit with the torch, propane, flux, and solder for less than $20).

Comment: @Tester101 Why not simply a double-female compression fitting with another 12-inch length copper pipe? I just saw one for under $6, rated at 250F, available from Ferguson.

Comment: @Upnorth that would work, as long as it's rated for over 210°F and 150 psi. Can you link to the product you found? The cheapest I found a 3/4" compression coupling was $11.

Comment: @Tester101  Oops. Sorry... the one I spotted was 1/2", although they have a 5/8 for $7.  The 3/4" one I see on eBay is, in fact, $11.